# How to return valid JSON format from db through swagger in .net 6

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, encoding

I have nvarchar content in my db like:
`"{"prop1": {"test7": "test"}}"`
and my program return is like:

```
"{\r\n  \"prop":{\r\n  \"test7":\"test"}"
```

Return method has return type `async Task<IActionResult>` and it returns like `return Ok(response)`

What I want is to have proper json format with indentation instead.
I use System.Json as well as NewtonsoftJson library. Booth cases are fine for me. I believe is something due encoding but I'm not sure. Thanks

UPDATE #1:
It looks like its not problem with my swagger, but with my _dbcontext.

```
var allByExternalId = _requests.Where(x => x.CorrelationId == correlationId); //this line return IQueryable with property which contains CRLF
```

How to tell EF COre not to parse this string as CRLF but to keep json indentation? thanks

Comment: \r\n is CRLF (essentially a newline) when rendered, and it does look like there is some indentation going in your sample. Please include an example of the exact format you're looking for because what you posted as the incorrect format sounds correct to your spec

Comment: please see my update#1

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand. You don't want newlines but you do want indentation? I don't think that's what you're saying but the wording is a little confusing.

Comment: It will help if you include a sample of what you *do* want your returned json to look like